# How do I fix my linux kernel to support my touchpad?

Tags: linux, touchpad, thinkpad

What I want to do is to solve why my touchpad on my ThinkPad T14s Gen 2 work awesome when cleanly booted, but lag as hell when in between hibernation in Arch Linux (tested all kernels) and also tried Ubuntu and it is the same thing, so must be the kernel. Anyway, I love this laptop but need this to work, so want to solve it myself.

How do I get started?

It feels so intimidating to improve and implement a feature to a kernel.

Comment: [AMD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T14_(AMD)_Gen_2) or [Intel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T14/T14s_(Intel)_Gen_2)? And do you have the latest BIOS?

Comment: If you remove and then reload the kernel module handling the touchpad, does it return to normal performance?

Comment: @Freddy Intel and I think so but will have to double check.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes it does, something just happen when the PC come back from hibernation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The touchpad was fixed in BIOS version 1.48, current version is 1.51 (16 Jan 2023).

[BIOS Update (Utility & Bootable CD) for Windows 11, 10 (64-bit), Linux - ThinkPad T14s Gen 2 (Type 20WM, 20WN), X13 Gen 2 (Type 20WK, 20WL)](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds549521-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-10-64-bit-linux-thinkpad-t14s-gen-2-type-20wm-20wn-x13-gen-2-type-20wk-20wl)

From the [README](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n35ul13w.txt) (n35ul13w.txt):

```
 UEFI: 1.48 / ECP: 1.40
 - [Important] Updated includes security fixes.
 - [Important] Enhancement to address security vulnerability:
               CVE-2021-33122, CVE-2021-33123, CVE-2021-33124, CVE-2021-33103
 - (New) Updated the Diagnostics module to version 04.25.000.
 - (New) Updated the E-Labeling applcation to version 5.1.0.39.
 - (New) Updated Synaptics fingerprint EFI driver to version 6.0.29.1136.
 - (Fix) Fixed an issue where touch panel might not work on Linux after resume, if "Linux S3"
         is set on "Sleep State" in BIOS Setup.
```

Comment: Thank you so much!